# Segmentation Fault when trying to open input file into array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fstream

I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to this simple Music sorting application I'm trying to create. I've been wrestling with it for awhile and trying different things, but no matter what I keep getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <string>    
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Constants
const int MAX_CHAR = 101;
const int SONG_CAPACITY = 100;

struct song {
char title[MAX_CHAR];
char artist[MAX_CHAR];
char album[MAX_CHAR];
char duration[MAX_CHAR];
};

//Function Prototypes
void dispLibrary(song library[], int& index);
void loadLibrary(const char fileName[], song library[], int& index);
void addEntry(const char fileName[], song library[], int& index);

int main(){
int command;
song library[SONG_CAPACITY];
int index = 0;
char fileName[] = "songs.txt";

loadLibrary(fileName, library, index);
while(command != 5){
    cout << "Please select an action (1-5): ";
    cin >> command;
    switch(command){
        case 1:
             dispLibrary(library, index);
             break;
        case 2:
             break;
        case 3:
             break;
        case 4:
             break;
        case 5:
             break;
    }
}
}

void addEntry(const song& entry, song library[], int& index)
{
strcpy(library[index].title, entry.title);
strcpy(library[index].artist, entry.artist);
strcpy(library[index].album, entry.album);
strcpy(library[index].duration, entry.duration);
index++;
}

void loadLibrary(const char fileName[], song library[], int& index)
{
ifstream        songFile;
char            title[MAX_CHAR];
char            artist[MAX_CHAR];
char            album[MAX_CHAR];
char            duration[MAX_CHAR];
song            entry;

songFile.open(fileName);
if(!songFile)
{
    songFile.clear();
    cerr << endl << "Fail to open " << fileName << " for input!" << endl     << endl;
    //exit(1);
}

songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';');
while (!songFile.eof())
{
    songFile.get();                                     
    songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    songFile.get(artist, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    songFile.get(album, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    songFile.get(duration, MAX_CHAR, '\n');
    songFile.ignore(100, '\n');             

    strcpy(entry.title, title);
    strcpy(entry.artist, artist);
    strcpy(entry.album, album);
    strcpy(entry.duration, duration);

    addEntry(entry, library, index);

    songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';');     //start the next record
}
songFile.close();
}

void dispLibrary(song library[], int& index){
int i;
cout << setw(10) << "Title" << setw(10) << "Artist" << setw(10) << "Album" << setw(10) << "Duration" << endl;
for(i=0; i<index; i++)
{
    cout << setw(10) << library[i].title << setw(10) << library[i].artist << endl;
}
}
```

I really want to know why this code crashes with a segmentation fault, any input is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Where is the segmentation fault?  What's the output you get when it crashes?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code to see where  the segfault happens?  You should look into using a `std::strind` instead of C strings

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm In Windows, the program just crashes, but in Linux it just says "Segmentation fault" It occurs when I open the input file, as when I comment out that line, the program runs through without error.

Comment: @NathanOliver You're telling me! It's a requirement for this class that I use Cstrings instead of the C++ string class. It's sure made everything a lot more frustrating.

Comment: Does your input file have more than 100 songs in it?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm My input file only has two entries in it. They're in this format: title;artist;album;duration \n

Comment: If you think that opening the file is what causes the segfault, then *remove everything else*. Strip away as much code as possible while still producing the error, and see what's left.

Comment: `100 * (4 * 101) byte` is not something you want to put onto the stack.

Comment: Is your question, "What causes a segmentation fault and how do I debug it?"

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you `get` the title far more times than it appears in the file. Supposing your file contains this:

```
title;artist;album;duration
title2;artist2;album2;duration
```

...I'll add some comments after each line that reads from the file to show what's still unread:

```
songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';'); // Read the first title.

/* artist;album;duration
 * title2;artist2;album2;duration
 */

while (!songFile.eof())
{
    songFile.get();  // Read the 'a' in "artist".                        

/* rtist;album;duration
 * title2;artist2;album2;duration
 */

    songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';'); // Read "rtist;", overwriting the title var that has already been read.

/* album;duration
 * title2;artist2;album2;duration
 */

    songFile.get(artist, MAX_CHAR, ';'); // Read "album;" into the artist variable.

/* duration
 * title2;artist2;album2;duration
 */
    songFile.get(album, MAX_CHAR, ';'); // Read "duration\ntitle2;" into the album variable.
                                        // Ignores the newline while it searches for the next semicolon.

/* artist2;album2;duration
 */
    songFile.get(duration, MAX_CHAR, '\n'); // Read until the second newline.

/* EOF */

    songFile.ignore(100, '\n');       // Read past the EOF. 
                                      // If there was a third record, this would skip it.

    strcpy(entry.title, title);
    strcpy(entry.artist, artist);
    strcpy(entry.album, album);
    strcpy(entry.duration, duration);

    addEntry(entry, library, index);

    songFile.get(title, MAX_CHAR, ';');     // Read past EOF again.
                                            // If there was a fourth record,
                                            // this would create the same
                                            // problem that was caused by
                                            // reading the title before
                                            // entering the while loop.
}
songFile.close();
}
```